# How to check if letters in a word are in alphabetical order?

Tags: c#

There are a couple of words in English language that consist of letters, which are in alphabetical order, namely: hot, fry, fuzz, am, in, hoops and almost.

I need a method that checks if letters in a word satisfy above specifications.

All I could think of is to create an alphabet array, and test if each consecutive letter has a higher index in the alphabet array.

Comment: You can compare strings with greater than and less than. I'd just start at the beginning and return false if the the next letter is less than the current letter.

Comment: post the code you have.

Comment: I don't have any code yet. I'm trying to get on the right track, before attempting.

Comment: Simple your string is a character array so sort that alphabetically and see if its same as the original string. I'll post solution when not on phone

Comment: Do you care only about the Latin alphabet with no accents?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string s = "hoops";
bool inOrder = s == String.Join("", s.OrderBy(c => c));
```

or

```
bool inOrder = s.SequenceEqual(s.OrderBy(c => c));
```

Comment: +1 for very slick implementation, however its worth noting the order is case sensitive.

Comment: Exactly what I was goin to do +1

Comment: In my example, the word is lowercase.

Comment: @RomanGusan you should definitely mark this as the answer.  The solution is elegant and best of all simple!

Answer (score 5):

The other answers create temporary strings and also run through all letters unnecessarily. Try this :) (I'm assuming case sensitivity doesn't matter).

```
bool LettersAreInAlphabeticalOrder(string word)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.ToLower(word[i]) < Char.ToLower(word[i - 1]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a longer way to implement the task, but it gets the job done.

Comment: It is a bit more verbose but it will perform much better if you have a lot of words to work with. It avoids creating lots of temporary strings and also avoids O(n(log(n))) sorting :)

Comment: This provides MUCH better performance than string joins and LINQ functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple non-linq function, in case you have to use .net 2.0 like me for example :)

```
  private bool isAlphabetic(string toCheck)
  {
     toCheck = toCheck.ToLower();
     for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.Length; i++)
     {
        if (i+1 < toCheck.Length && toCheck[i] > toCheck[i + 1])
           return false;
     }

     return true;
  }
```

Comment: I think you should combine the two `Length` conditions: `for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.Length - 1; i++)`